# df to sql server replace

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, syntax, screen-scraping

im doing scraping web and want to save my dataframe to my sql server that updates everymonth,what should i add to code for the data got replaced not added.im using pyodbc(i cant use sql achemy)thank you in advance.

```py
col_names = ["month", "price", "change"]
df = pd.read_csv("minyak_brent.csv",sep=',',quotechar='\'',encoding='utf8', names=col_names,skiprows = 1) # Replace Excel_file_name with your excel sheet name
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.minyak_brent([month],[price],[change]) values (?,?)', 
                    row['month'], 
                    row['price'], 
                    row['change'])
                    
    cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `df.to_sql` here, which avoids the need to explicitly iterate over your Pandas data frame:

```py
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='dbo.minyak_brent', if_exists='append', dtype={
    'month': STRING(255),
    'price': FLOAT,
    'change': FLOAT, index=False
)
```

This assumes that the types of the `month`, `price`, and `change` columns are, `String(255)`, `FLOAT`, and `FLOAT`, respectively.

If you must stick with your current approach, then fix your insert statement such that it has the right number of placeholders in the `VALUES` clause:

```py
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO dbo.minyak_brent([month], [price], [change])
                  VALUES (?, ?, ?)''',  (row['month'], row['price'], row['change']))
```

Note that we insert a *tuple* as the second parameter to `cursor#execute`.

Comment: thank you! but  sorry i cannot use sql alchemy

Comment: Check the edit which fixes at least some of the problems with your current code.

Comment: yeah thank you! but it still got added..how to replace it?

Comment: You need to figure out first whether you want to _add_ new data or _modify_ data which already exists.  The two don't even use the same SQL commands; the first uses `INSERT`, the second `UPDATE`.  Your question never made it clear that you want to do anything other than an insert, hence my answer above.

Comment: sorry im very limited in english so i cant really write it out..how about use both with if-else,did it will work?

Comment: What you seem to want is _upsert_ functionality.  No one will be able to help you further unless you include sample data which explains what you want to have happen here.  There is no "quick" fix to what you asked; you have to explain what you want.